# jQuery updating via NuGet error

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have a problem. I have created new ASP.NET MVC application 4. It contains JQuery 1.8. But I wanna update it to 2.0 version. I try to use NuGet extension for updating but it isn't working and writing error message:

> User canceled out of save dialog  Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004000C (OLE_E_PROMPTSAVECANCELLED

Visual Studio version is 2012 ultimate update 2
Operating system is Windows 8 Professional

Can anyone help me?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English but it isn't my native language

Comment: Seems like a question you should be asking on [the NuGet issue tracker](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic) on CodePlex

Answer (score 0):

- If you create another ASP.NET MVC 4 and try to update jQuery, does the bug happen again? Is it just a jQuery issue?
- What are your exact Visual Studio and NuGet versions (Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio)?
- If you try to do it through Package Manager Console (Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console / You can use Get-Help NuGet to find the commands), does it happen too?